# Why my application ran by Fast Startup? How to prevent that?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Here's a weird one. My application(MFC, really out one) relies on a service(C++). Both app and service are my coding. And I found if I shutdown my PC while app running and power-on, the app will be ran by system. And it doesn't work well with my service.

To be more detailed, my app and service communicate through NamedPipe, so if the app ran by system, it could go wrong.

Which already has been confirmed is that if I turned off 'fast startup' in power option and my app won't run after a shutdown then power-on action any more.
My app won't run with 'restart' exactly match the description of 
[system option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seaO6.png)

I promised that I didn't add any 'let my app run by fast startup' that kind of code.

I'm really confusing right now and there're few articles about Windows Fast Startup mechanism. I did found an article from MSDN about fast-startup boot and cold boot. But it's all about drivers, not Win32 desktop apps.
Here's the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/distinguishing-fast-startup-from-wake-from-hibernation

Could anyone please help?

No code for now.

I don't want my app ran by system automatically.
(btw, in common sense, we should initially code for that, but

Comment: I think that your service recovery option is set to restart the service.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/mfc-restart-manager-support-in-vs2010/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry for that.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks very much, I'll take a look.